# Identify which webservices consumed higher

Tags: java, spring, web-services

We have few Webservices developed using spring and consumed by the Mobile APP, want to find which Webservices has been used more frequently.

How to mark the usage of the each webservice, please help. Is generic tool or classes available for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is writing an `interceptor` and putting your logic of counting in `preHandle()` method. You can log the request to log file and then at the end of the day run some program to check which was used mostly(analytic things) or you can write some code to count the hits in this method. Hope

Check [this](http://www.journaldev.com/2676/spring-mvc-interceptor-example-handlerinterceptor-handlerinterceptoradapter).

Hope this helps!